# knockout.js foreach - nice way of finding length?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using a `foreach` loop on an observable array.

I use `$index` to display some html slightly differently if `$index` is 0, or if it is the length of the array. Currently I use `$parent.myarray().length` but this feels clunky as I'm having to reach outside of the loop to reach something that seems like it should be right in front of me.

Is there some sort of `$length` or something similar?

([This link](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/532) makes me think there isn't a better way but I figured I would check.)

Edit: Forgot to mention that I've tried a few variations on `$data.length` or `$rawData.length` but none of those seemed to be working.

Comment: Can you craft a small repro with a view model and view? There probably is a solution but without some more details about your situation there's too many variations in how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

From the official Knockout [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html), the only way to access the underlying array length is by first unwrapping the observable:

```
alert('The length of the array is ' + myObservableArray().length);
```

I don't think the link you referenced made it into the Knockout core (yet).